# python login freenom using session

Tags: python, session, authentication

Trying to make a script updating my url forwarding in freenom while blocked by the web login using pythong. I google quite a lot working code but none is working for me.

Following is an most common code I get:

```
import requests

url = "https://my.freenom.com/clientarea.php?action=emails"
payload = {'username': 'mytest@gmail.com', 'password': 'mypassword'}
with requests.session() as s:
    # fetch the login page
    s.get(url)
    # post to the login form
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    print(r.content)
```

And when I save the print into html, I see it is not the logined page.Any body see any obvious problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, although I can use

```
url = "https://my.freenom.com/clientarea.php?action=emails"
```

for login in explorer, but when I use another address,

```
"https://my.freenom.com/dologin.php"
```

my script is then work.

Anybody can explain why?